# Two date column ordering according to special logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, t-sql

I need some help getting the following desired order with a query, I have hardcoded the desired order below. I need to sort by column date OR by create date if date column is null but **prioritizing [date] where is not null**, as follows

| Create Date | Date | Desired Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 14:09:00.000 | NULL | 1 |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:03.000 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:04.000 | NULL | 3 |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:02.000 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 4 |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:00.000 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 5 |

```
drop table if exists #a

create table #a(
    create_date datetime,
    [date] datetime,
    [desired_order] int,
    primary key ([create_date])
);

insert into #a values('20170101 14:09:00.000', NULL,  1);
insert into #a values('20170101 14:10:00.000', '20210101',5);
insert into #a values('20170101 14:10:03.000', '20190101', 2);
insert into #a values('20170101 14:10:04.000', NULL, 3);
insert into #a values('20170101 14:10:02.000', '20200101', 4);

select * from #a order by desired_order
```

**Further explanation from comments:** In the first instance I want to order by create_date but any date values which appear out of order i.e. where a more recent date appears in an earlier row then it needs to be moved to the end of the result set and any such rows ordered by date.

**After accepting an answer:** I found a set of data that breaks the accepted solution:

```
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:09:00.000', NULL);
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:00.000', '20210101');
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:05.000', '20180101');
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:03.000', '20160101');
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:02.000', '20160205');
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:04.000', NULL);
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:01.000', '20200101');
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:06.000', '20230101');
insert into #a(create_date, [date]) values('20170101 14:10:07.000', '20170101');
```

For some reason the 2017 precedes the 2016 date, I appreciate your help.

**Solution that passes all test cases:**

```
;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT 
        create_date, 
        [DATE],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CREATE_DATE) CN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DATE]) DN
  FROM #a
)
select *
from 
    cte1
order by 
    case when [date] is null then CN else DN end, 
    CREATE_DATE
```

Comment: What's wrong with `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`?

Comment: order by coalesce([date],[create_date]) will show the two null date rows FIRST, and that is not what I want, please see the table above.

Comment: Can you explain why a date like 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 is 2nd?

Comment: *"I need to sort by column date OR by create date if date column is null, as follows"* but the following data doesn't follow that requirement. If it did, the 2nd row wouldn't be 2nd, it would be 3rd.

Comment: amended explanation, hope that helps

Comment: That doesnt change the requirements. The description and expected output do not match.

Comment: the short story is that I need to prioritize the date where is not null instead of prioritizing nulls in the order by, so coalesce(date, create_date) does not work here.

Comment: that's why I'm here...

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @DaleK I'm a little dubious on reopening this; the description and the dupe do align and the OP can't seem to  explain the logic they do want. If I were to be voting to open, I'd be voting to close again as unclear... As such, I don't feel it's correct to reopen a question I'd still VTC.

Comment: That's fine, more than happy to if they do.

Comment: They've copy pasted what you commented, it's not their own words (which I don't think really helps in some ways) but I've reopened @DaleK .

Comment: it doesn't have to be my own words if there is a better way to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a very odd requirement. You can solve this using the `min` analytic function to find whether there is a smaller value of `date` ahead of us. Here is a possible solution with comments to explain the logic:

```
with cte1 as (
  select *
    -- Find the smallest value between this row and the last row
    , min([Date]) over (partition by case when [date] is not null then 1 else 0 end order by create_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) mindate
  from #a
)
select create_date, [date]
  -- Testing - uncomment to see how the logic works
  --, desired_order, mindate
from cte1
-- If no date, always keep in the first section, and order by create_date
-- If there is a date, check whether this date is greater than the smallest date ahead of us, and if so move ahead
order by case when [date] is null then 0 else case when [date] > [mindate] then 1 else 0 end end, case when [date] > [mindate] then [date] else create_date end;
```

Returns:

| create_date | date |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 14:09:00.000 | NULL |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:03.000 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:04.000 | NULL |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:02.000 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-01 14:10:00.000 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 |

Note: I can't be sure that this functions correctly across all edge cases as your sample data is very brief.

Comment: you were right, I found a set of data that breaks the accepted logic, I have updated the question, I appreciate your help.

Comment: hi, sorry to be a pain, but found another problem, see updated "After accepting answer" insert data

Comment: @Alex 2 things, its really bad form to keep changing the goal posts. You need to ensure any question you ask covers all edge cases in advance. Second, I've given you a good starting point... rather than asking me to adapt this query to meet your new data, have a go yourself and make sense of the logic and how you might adjust it to meet your new requirements. You're also missing your desired order from your new dataset.